# Efficient extracting all files from a zip file

Tags: c#, .net, dotnetzip

What is the most efficient way to extract all the files from a zip file (and store them in a dictionary file_name->contents) using [DotNetZip](http://dotnetzip.codeplex.com/)? The zip is in a slow network location, so I want to make sure it is (a) downloaded and (b) decompressed only once.

Answer (score 0):

There is not much to do here, then

1) download the file

2) unzip it localy

You need (1) to avoid expensive permission check on every network access.

Just one more point: make sure that you download/unzip into the location were *current user* has read/write permission.

For example, it could be:

```
var path = Path.Combine(
    Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonApplicationData),
    APP_NAME);
```

which results on Windows7 in `C:\ProgramData\APP_NAME`

Comment: A *temporary*, *user-specific* location would probably be a better choice than `CommonApplicationData`. The zip file is basically a download that's being thrown away after extraction.